# Querying a website database from a C# console application

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to write a simple app in C# that will query a database available to the public located at https://newswire.theunderminejournal.com/

They give an example located at https://newswire.theunderminejournal.com/sample2.php

As far as I know, the server I'm trying to connect to is "newswire.theunderminejournal.com" and the database is "newsstand".

This gives me a string of:

```
string connection_str ="Server=newsstand.theunderminejournal.com;Database=newsstand";
```

My code looks like this:

```
xData = "Unable to connect to database.";
string server = "'newswire.theunderminejournal.com'";
//string server = "45.75.164.122";
string database = "'newsstand'";
string connection_str = string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};", server, database);
Console.WriteLine(connection_str);

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connection_str);

try
{
   connection.Open();
   xData = "Connection established!";                
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   xData = e.Message;                
}

connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
```

This results only in an error message:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occured while not
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  (provider:
>   Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)"

I've pinged the server, getting an IP address at 45.79.164.122 and no issues at all pinging it.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?  I'm brand new to C# so if there is another/better way of doing this, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: Are there no username and password required to connect to the database?

Comment: Sure you may be able to ping it, but to open a connection, do you not have login credentials?

Comment: Oops, sorry, no, there is no need for user\pass.  The person explicitly says to not log in with a user\pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a `SqlConnection` to a mySQL database, which is why the error message refers to *"… establishing a connection to **SQL Server**."*.

You need to [use a MySqlConnection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html) instead, which you get when you install Connector/Net - which you can download from Oracle [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: That link is a bit dated. I believe 6.9.9 is what is current direct from Oracle

Comment: This was the issue.  Thank you!